# Script that replaces certain words with corresponding unicode characters not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to replace certain words in the anchors of my `<nav>`, one word per anchor, with a Unicode character.

But, this script doesn't seem to be working as the text in the view-source is the words and not the Unicode characters...

What am I doing wrong?

And is there a better way to do what I am trying to do that this script:

```
$("nav li a").text(function(i,currentText) {
    switch($(this).innerHTML()){
        case "CV":
            return currentText.replace(/CV/g, "&#xe00c;");
            break;
        case "down":
            return currentText.replace(/down/g, "&#xe00d;");
            break;
        case "Work":
            return currentText.replace(/Work/g, "&#xe010;");
            break;
        case "About":
            return currentText.replace(/About/g, "&#xe00f;");
            break;
        case "Resume":
            return currentText.replace(/Resume/g, "&#xe00e;");
            break;
        case "Mail":
            return currentText.replace(/Mail/g, "&#xe011;");
            break;
        case "Facebook":
            return currentText.replace(/Facebook/g, "&#xe013;");
            break;
        case "Twitter":
            return currentText.replace(/Twitter/g, "&#xe014;");
            break;
        case "Dribbble":
            return currentText.replace(/Dribbble/g, "&#xe015;");
            break;
        default:
            break;      
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to replace the HTML with HTML entities, but you're calling `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

There's no need to use `.replace()`, since you're going to be replacing the whole string anyway.  Just return the entity.

You won't see your changes in the "view source" view. That just shows the source as it was when the page was loaded.

You should return "currentText" if you don't make any replacements.

```
$("nav li a").html(function(i, curHtml) {
  switch(curHtml){
    case "CV":
        return "&#xe00c;";

    case "down":
        return "&#xe00d;";

    // etc

    default:
      return currentHtml;
});
```

Comment: so I should replace .text() with .html(), but then what do I replace .replace() with ?

Comment: I was actually viewing the elements in the dev console / tools so the content would change as JS manipulates it.

Comment: @ArashDonsaliKapoor you don't need replace at all.  Just return the entity string.